# Merge Replication Business Logic Handler Incorrect Encoding when connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, merge-replication, encoding

We have a SQL Server Merge Replication configuration that uses a business logic handler to do conflict resolution on a datetimeoffset column.

All we're doing is a copy of the Subscriber or Publisher dataset to the CustomDataset in the `UpdateConflictsHandler` function and logging the win. When profiling we see the below, where it appears that all non-datetime date and time types (datetime2, datetimeoffset, date, time) are being mangled by adding spaces between each character.

We are surmising that somehow after our function returns the column is being encoded as UTF-16 and decoded by SQL Server as UTF-8. Is there any way to fix this? It seems to be happening wholly outside of our code. (SQL Server 2008R2, with Merge Replication through IIS over web)

```
exec [MSmerge_cft_sp_7BF3FB7C8F8D4A33D64FC13EF2DE42B6] '4BCCFA1D-891F-4E7D-9A0B-000409743B2B'
,1000001001,'','JOHN','TestCorp2322'
,'Smith',NULL,NULL
,'2 0 1 3 - 0 4 - 2 0   1 7 : 0 1 : 3 1 . 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   - 0 7 : 0 0'
,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,0,0,N'',NULL,NULL,1,0
,'2 0 1 8 - 0 4 - 1 8   1 1 : 0 8 : 4 0 . 4 7 2 5 2 7 2   - 0 7 : 0 0 '
,1,NULL,1,1,1,NULL,'4BC6FA1D-891F-4E7D-9C0B-000409793B2B',N'PUBLISHER-NAME',1,1,N'The same row was updated at both ''SUBSCRIBER.RepTest11'' and ''PUBLISHER.RepTestCorp''. The resolver chose the update from ''SUBSCRIBER.RepTest11'' as the winner.','D64FC13E-F2DE-42B6-A40E-05DF4159644F',0x00,46258027,'D64FC13E-F2DE-42B6-A40E-05DF4159644F',0
```

Comment: Does this happen with regular `DATETIME` values or just `DATETIMEOFFSET`? The string parameters all seem to be handled correctly. It looks like an issue with whatever code generates that T-SQL. The DATETIMEOFFSET values coming from the DB shouldn't be strings, so this should be happening on the way out. Are you getting errors because of this? or is it purely an issue with how it appears in SQL Server Profiler?

Comment: Just offsets, as far as I can tell. My merge conflict resolver works correctly on a test table with only DATETIMES

Comment: All I get in my UpdateConflictsHandler function is a publisherDataSet and a subscriberDataSet. They're both C# `System.Data.DataSet` objects, and the datatypes of nearly all the fields is either System.String, GUID, or Int, and I only pass back which one is the winner.

Comment: I assume you pass back the object / reference and not a custom DataSet that you created, right? Meaning, the datatypes were all assigned automatically and you didn't have a hand in that. Is the datatype for the offset column in both `DataSet`s `DateTimeOffset` or `System.String`? It kinda looks like it is being mishandled as a string.

Comment: Also, I highly doubt that the problem is within SQL Server. This is getting messed up before it gets there. If SQL Server was misinterpreting the incoming value(s), then the entire thing would be double-spaced. Which actually leads to a question: are you seeing exactly that in SQL Server Profiler? If so, then it is being passed in as a full string (i.e. _not_ a parameterized query). Otherwise you would see parameters being passed into that stored proc (i.e. `@p1`). So whatever is building that query is misunderstanding how to handle `DATETIMEOFFSET`.

Comment: My code paste above is exactly from Profiler (anonymized, but otherwise identical). I've tried both AcceptPublisher/ AcceptSubscriber and doing `CustomDataSet = PublisherDataset.Copy()` with AcceptCustomConflictData as i've found in online examples.  Both ways fail. The datatypes for all fields are as they come in to my function. There are only System.Strings, int / float types, and GUID types.

Comment: Well, the fact that the query is a copy and paste from SQL Profiler proves that the problem is entirely outside of SQL Server as it is happening before the query is submitted. There is a bug in either the code that builds the query, or the code that detects the datatype of the incoming columns. When the table has a `DATETIME` column, is there a `DateTime` type in the `DataSet`? I found https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0616e227-fc45-40fc-b118-094f84f54aab/streamblobcolumns?forum=sqlreplication which seems related as option 0x200000000 deals with this, but maybe not?

Comment: Right, the Replication Agent is a dll loaded in IIS, which in turn loads my buisness logic handler, but the transformation is happening after my code, back in Microsoft's logic, but before SQL. There are no datatypes in the dataset other than listed above. Only strings, ints, floats, and GUIDs. I believe somewhere along the line there is a UTF-8 => UTF-16 => UTF-8 conversion happening on these fields that's not being handled properly, and I know that text that's in UTF-16 viewed as UTF-8 appears with spaces between each character.

Comment: That conversion issue happens when going from UTF-16 to either UTF-8 or an 8-bit code page. But, yes, this is happening in Microsoft's code and they don't have public reference code for this stuff. Are you saying that even with a `DATETIME` column you still only have that list of types in the `DataSet` and no .NET `DateTime` type? UTF-8 is not really in .NET or SQL Server, so it could be happening in IIS, but I don't think so because other string / date values are fine. It looks like an issue coming into ReplicationAgent since it shows the type as `String` and not `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: Correct, even with DateTimes the datacolumns are type System.String. I turn them into DateTimes for comparison with TryParse(), but I never set any values in any of the datasets. I just make the decision and return the winner.

Comment: I know this isn't your code, but can you use the .NET / VS debugger to capture the value of the `datetimeoffset`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76331/discussion-between-solomon-rutzky-and-jason).